# Xamarin iOS splash keeps loosing images

Tags: xamarin.ios

This is a weird problem. I created a storyboard to use for our splash screen. It has 2 ImageViews in it. I do a build and everything looks.

Every so often, for some unknown reason, the images will stop displaying. Sometimes it's one of them and sometimes both. What's even stranger is that the images continue to display elsewhere in the app.
What I ended up doing is creating a copy of the images so now there is background.png, background2.png, logo.png and logo2.png.

So when the image stops displaying, I switch to the copy and then it works right.

This has been a work around but is not a solution. I can't seem to figure out what the issue is.

What makes this even worse is, sometimes it happens when I change to an ad-hoc build and then deploy to TestFlight so we don't see the issue until we install it from TestFlight.

Comment: I ranked that question up because I'm facing the same issue. I did not find any workable solutions so far.

Comment: I've seen this before, I would delete the MTBS folders for the project/app on the mac, and then rebuild the project, it should solve your image issues.

Comment: I use Xamarin/VS on Windows. Where is the MTBS folder?

Comment: @Digitalsa1nt thank you, it helped me!

Comment: @jbassking10 the MTBS folder is in the build folder on the apple mac that you must be connecting to in order to test/simulate your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I've seen this issue before on a couple of the projects I've worked on in the past. it's a strange situation where resources aren't copied accross to the build folder on the mac, most likely caused by something not working correctly with the Xamarin build process for that specific project.

The solution that I've used in the past is to simply delete the 'mtbs' folder that is situated on the apple Mac that you are building/compiling your project to.

The location can be found below:

> ~/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/[Long project Guid]

The long guid can be seen in the output window in visual studio when you build your project, but if this is your first project you may likely only have one folder here.

If you simply delete the folder that relates to your project, and then run 'Rebuild', it should push across any necessary resources that it was missing out before, including images.